# How Exactly Does @param Work - Java

Tags: java, param

How does the annotation `@param` work?

If I had something like this:

```
/* 
*@param testNumber;
*/

int testNumber = 5;
if (testNumber < 6) {
   //Something
}
```

How would the `@param` affect the testNumber? Does it even affect the testNumber?

Thanks. Let me know if I used it wrong.

Comment: blocks that start with `/**` and end with `*/` are processed by `javadoc` only. They are treated as `comments` by Java compiler.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`@param` won't affect the number. It's just for making javadocs.

More on javadoc:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Comment: This is correct, as far as I'm aware. You could put `@param blahblah` and it would make the JD generate for the parameter `blahblah`.

Comment: param doesn't affect the method. It will show you what you need when looking at the details for the method (hover mouse over method after pressing . ) You could even add more after @param to provide more information on the parameter

Answer (score 45):

`@param` is a special format comment used by **javadoc** to generate documentation. it is used to denote a description of the parameter (or parameters) a method can receive. there's also `@return` and `@see` used to describe return values and related information, respectively:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#format

has, among other things, this:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
```

Answer (score 6):

`@param` will not affect testNumber.It is a `Javadoc` comment - i.e used for generating documentation .
You can put a `Javadoc` comment immediately before a class, field, method, constructor, or interface such as `@param`, `@return` .
Generally begins with '**@**' and must be the first thing on the line.

The Advantage of using `@param` is :- 
By creating simple Java classes that contain attributes and some custom Javadoc tags, you allow those classes to serve as a simple metadata description for code generation.

```
    /* 
       *@param testNumber
       *@return integer
    */
    public int main testNumberIsValid(int testNumber){

       if (testNumber < 6) {
          //Something
        }
     }
```

Whenever in your code if you reuse testNumberIsValid method, IDE will show you the parameters the method accepts and return type of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You might miss @author and inside of @param you need to explain what's that parameter for, how to use it, etc.

Comment: Oh, sorry I meant @param

Answer (score 0):

It is basically a comment. As we know, a number of people working on the same project must have knowledge about the code changes. We are making some notes in the program about the parameters.