# Unable to pass positional parameters into HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Whilst trying to create an API for my app I tried to make a query that takes a value passed in and then returns the response from the db.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userID = ?")
User getUserById(String id);
```

I have created queries this way in other projects but cannot figure out why I get the following error on this project

```
JDBC style parameters (?) are not supported for JPA queries.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

have you tried this :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userID  = :id")
User getUserById(String id);
```

Comment: This works... is there any documentation I can read to see why this works?

Comment: you can read more from this : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-the-query-annotation/

Comment: Is it necessary to annotate id parameter with @Param ? User getUserById(@Param String id);

Comment: @OrçunÇolak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138217/how-exactly-does-param-work-java

Answer (score 4):

Encounter the same problem in HQL, in **XML** approach with **positional** Parameter

**Exception:** Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported

[image]

**HQL Query**

```
String hql = "from Customer cust where cust.city=?";
```

**Solution:** Change the hql query as below

```
String hql = "from Customer cust where cust.city=?0";
```

And here we go!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Legacy-style query parameters (`?`) are no longer supported;
```

This is because **hibernate** does not provide support to **placeholders (?)** , you need to change your code to following which uses `named parameters` in hibernate.

It works.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userID = :inputUserId")
User getUserById(String inputUserId);

:inputUserId // named parameter
```

Following is the reason to avoid **placeholders (?)**.

> Deprecate the Hibernate-specific (JDBC-style) positional parameters in
>   favor of the JPA-style.

Answer (score 1):

```
String hql = "from Customer cust where cust.city= :city";
Query<Customer> query = session.createQuery(hql,Customer.Class);
query.setParameter("city",id);//here id is your value
```

Answer (score 1):

I have presented 2 example on how to write parameterized query in hibernate.

```
package demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import demo.entity.Student;

public class UpdateDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create session factory
        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();

        // create session
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();

        try {

            // start a transaction
            session.beginTransaction();

            // query student table
            List<Student> theStudents = session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList();

            // Example1: Query with parameter
            String sql = "from Student s where s.firstName=?0 and s.lastName=?1";
            theStudents = session.createQuery(sql).setParameter(0, "Norman").setParameter(1, "Brandon").list();
            displayResult(theStudents);

            //Example 2: Query with Parameter
            String sql1 = "from Student s where s.firstName=:fname and s.lastName=:lname";
            Query<Student> query = session.createQuery(sql1);
            query.setParameter("fname", "John");
            query.setParameter("lname", "Doe");
            theStudents = query.list();
            displayResult(theStudents);

            // commit transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } finally {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

    private static void displayResult(List<Student> theStudents) {
        for (Student tempStudent : theStudents) {
            System.out.println(tempStudent);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `nativeQuery = true` after the query

> @Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userID = ?", nativeQuery
> = true)
>
> User getUserById(String id);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?1` since you have one input parameter in getUserById():

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userID = ?1")
User getUserById(String id);
```